# For $\text{Im}(z) > 0$, describe all solutions to $\cos(c z) = iz$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}, c > 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

A complex plot of the above equation shows that there are infinitely many solutions in the upper half plane, equally spaced in real parts, but with imaginary parts growing logarithmically. I'm having trouble finding an exact description of these solutions.

Writing $z = x + iy$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, the equation becomes $\cos(c(x+iy)) = i(x + iy)$, which after equating real and imaginary parts becomes the system of equations

$\begin{align*}
\cos(cx)\cosh(cy) &= -y\\
-\sin(cx)\sinh(cy) &= x.
\end{align*}$

I'm not sure if there's a nice way to express the solutions to this system. I can solve for one of the variables (for instance, using the second equation to solve for $y$), but substituting back into the first equation gives a highly nonlinear equation in $x$, and I'm not sure how to describe the solutions.

Comment: Express cos(cz) in terms of its Re/Im parts, and set them equal to i(a+bi).

Comment: I tried doing that, and I get a system of equations involving hyperbolic trig functions, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: you should show the attempts you made

Comment: I put what I wrote in the post.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to write your system of equations is:

$$\cos(cx)(e^{-cy} + e^{cy}) = - 2y$$
$$\sin(cx)(e^{-cy} - e^{cy}) = 2x$$

From the Pythagorean identity $\cos^2(cx) + \sin^2(cx) = 1$, we get:

$$\frac{4y^2}{(e^{-cy} + e^{cy})^2} + \frac{4x^2}{(e^{-cy} - e^{cy})^2} = 1$$

which can  be solved for $x$ in terms of $y$.

$$x = \pm \frac{e^{-cy} - e^{cy}}{2}\sqrt{1 - \frac{4y^2}{(e^{-cy} + e^{cy})^2}}$$

Alternatively, we can solve the original system of equations for $e^{cy}$ and $e^{-cy}$.

$$e^{cy} = \frac{-y}{\cos(cx)} - \frac{x}{\sin(cx)}$$
$$e^{-cy} = \frac{-y}{\cos(cx)} + \frac{x}{\sin(cx)}$$

But since these are reciprocals of each other, we have

$$\left( \frac{-y}{\cos(cx)} - \frac{x}{\sin(cx)} \right) \left( \frac{-y}{\cos(cx)} + \frac{x}{\sin(cx)} \right) = 1$$
$$\frac{y^2}{\cos^2(cx)}  - \frac{x^2}{\sin^2(cx)} = 1$$

and solving for $y$ in terms of $x$ gives:

$$y = \pm \cos(cx) \sqrt{1 + \frac{x^2}{\sin^2(cx)}}$$

Comment: Thanks. Is there an explanation for this approximately periodic behavior I'm observing in the real parts, along with the logarithmic growth I'm observing in the complex parts? I've noticed that the set $\frac{2n\pi}{c} + i\frac{2\log|2n\pi c^{-1}|}{c}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ forms a remarkably close approximation to the roots, getting better as $c \to \infty$.